# Howto install onto a software RAID?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, raid

I am trying to install onto an ASUS system with an LSI (fake) raid controller.  Unlike debian, ubuntu 14 detected it and installed drivers and utilities.  Then it creates a RAID 1 as directed.  All is well.

But it fails to install a boot loader, grub or lilo.  No error details, just "failed to install".  So sad.  I tried to create a partition for /boot and not have it be part of the RAID but it fails.

How do I install a boot loader onto a RAID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to try boot-repair.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_:_get_a_disk_including_Boot-Repair

Comment: This worked.  I followed the prompts and ran several commands as directed.

Answer (score 1):

The installer should default to the correct location, but if not, make sure it is set to install grub to the whole array ( /dev/mapper/something on older editions of Ubuntu, /dev/mdXX on recent releases if you have an Intel fakeraid ) rather than an individual drive ( /dev/sda ).

Comment: Thank you.  boot-repair installed it into  "/dev/mapper/something"

Comment: The boot loader installer failed.  I was not trying to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done automatically at the end of the Ubuntu server/desktop install. See this guide - [Official Ubuntu Guides](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID)

On my server, the boot loader got installed on both the HDD's directly (Raid1). If that fails, you can run this command for both your hard drives:

- grub-install /dev/sdX

X: is the letter of hard drives.

Comment: grub install fails

Comment: can you give more details on the error you are getting? Are you sure this is a software raid controller (or something that's embedded into the motherboard, but is para hardware)? 

Did you try creating a pure software raid directly in Ubuntu (ignoring the ASUS raid option)?

Comment: Official guide links to very old fake RAID guide:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto

Comment: grub-install: not found

Comment: Unable to install GRUB on /dev/md126p1

Comment: Unable to install GRUB on /dev/sdb1

Comment: No... you must not attempt to directly access individual drives that are part of a raid array.  You must install grub to the whole array instead.

Comment: @jnajna, you shouldn't even have a /dev/mdXXX  if this is a fakeraid ( except for Intel fakeraids on 15.04, which moved to mdadm ).

Comment: @psusi,  understood.  I think it turned out to be:  /dev/mapper/ddf1_4c53492020202020808627c3000000004711471100001450p1